# Criteria->with error, Id ambiguous

Tags: yii, model, criteria, relation, ambiguous

I have a problem with `$criteria->with`. I'm trying to search in a relation, but it keeps giving me the error: **"Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous"**. I searched for information on the issue and I found that I need an alias.

So, now I have this:

```
$q=$_POST['q'];
$url=Yii::app()->request->url;
$model=new Peticion('search');
$model->unsetAttributes();


$criteria->compare('t.id',$q,true, 'AND');
//$criteria->compare('decreto.ndecreto',$q,true, 'OR');
//$criteria->compare('decreto.gaceta',$q,true, 'OR');
$criteria->compare('t.tipos_id',$q,true, 'OR');
$criteria->compare('t.vendedor_id',$q,true, 'OR');
$criteria->compare('t.clientes_id',$q,true, 'OR');
$criteria->compare('t.fechacot',$q,true, 'OR');
$criteria->compare('t.metodologia',$q,true, 'OR');
$criteria->compare('t.fechaven',$q,true, 'OR');
$criteria->compare('t.departamento_id',$q,true, 'OR');
$criteria->compare('t.muestras_id',$q,true, 'OR');
$criteria->with = array( 'vendedor');
$criteria->compare('Vendedor.nombre',$q,true, 'OR');
```

$q is a string which I'm going to use to compare, so i thought it was a relation problem. Here are my relations:

Peticion Model (the table where I'm trying to search)

`'vendedor'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Vendedor','vendedor_id'),`

Vendedor Model (the relation)

`'peticion'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Peticion','peticion_id'),`

Why am I still getting the error?

Comment: how about changing 'Vendedor.nombre' to 'vendedor.nombre'

Comment: where are you using this criteria?

Comment: @tinybyte i did that, but nothing change

Comment: I think the error is from somewhere else, how are you using this criteria?

Comment: @tinybyte I'm using the criteria for a search box for all the page, I'm using it to search in "peticion", I'm using this criteria in peticion controller, in actionIndex

Comment: I meant to show with code

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
$criteria->with = array( 'vendedor' => array('alias'=>'v'));
$criteria->compare('v.nombre',$q,true, 'OR');
```

Comment: @xlembouras  i just try that, but still i got the error:
`Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 't'.'id') FROM 'peticion' 't' LEFT OUTER JOIN 'vendedor' 'v' ON ('t'.'vendedor_id'='v'.'id')`